# Angular JS - How to remove validations associated with dynamically removed inputs in a form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that adds and removes inputs on a form, recompiling after each set of additions and removals. My problem is that after removing inputs, the validations associated with the inputs seem to remain, so `$scope.contentEditorForm.$valid` is false and errors in `contentEditorForm.$error` exist for HTML inputs that no longer exist in the HTML DOM.

Inputs in the form are updated like so, where the current input HTML is emptied out before appending new HTML (where `element` is a container within the form):

```
$(element).empty();    

var result = $(formHtml).appendTo(element);

$compile(result)($scope);
```

On inspecting the Angular JS form object, I notice that properties are added for each input:

[image]

I have tried deleting these properties, but this makes no difference, the validation is obviously tracked elsewhere.

```
var propertyNameRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

for (var propertyName in $scope.contentEditorForm) {


    console.log('propertyName', propertyName)

    if(propertyNameRegEx.test(propertyName))
    {
        if (propertyName != 'title') {
            console.log('deleting propertyName', propertyName)

            delete $scope.contentEditorForm[propertyName];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove specific validations within the Angular JS managed form?

Comment: After removing the inputs try setting validity to be true using $setValidity().

Comment: Does using `$compile` in order to recompile the form element once the inputs are removed solve your issues?

Comment: @Mirceac21 - No this makes no difference apparently

Comment: @user3632710 - no, this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @gb2d can you add your directive codes in question...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I needed to clear the required errors array as well

```
$scope.contentEditorForm.$error.required = [];
```